# Pandas installed but not recognized

Tags: python, pandas

I already installed pandas, i did "sudo pip3 install pandas"
and got this back

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

but when i try to run a program, for example this simple script named Excel.py

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/justin/Desktop/midori.xls') 
print(data)
```

i get this error back when using "python3 Excel.py"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Excel.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

And when i use "python Excel.py" i get this back

```
    data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/justin/Desktop/midori.xls') 
  File "/Users/justin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/justin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/justin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/justin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/Users/justin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 393, in __init__
    raise ImportError(err_msg)
ImportError: Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You may have more than one python3. Try `sudo python3 -m pip install pandas` and see what happens. Depending on your OS, you may be better off either installing pandas through your regular package manager, or skipping the `sudo` and do `python3 -m pip install pandas` for a user space install that doesn't mess with the system version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice these days is to use a content manager like Anaconda. It will handle installing those tricky dependencies and save you a lot of headache

Comment: Yeah, i don't really know why i didn't save myself some time. I just did that and now it's working perfectly

Comment: Gald to have helped. Could you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> pip install pandas

Also if you are using anaconda distribution try

> conda install pandas

Also don't use sudo while installing package for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that you have multiple installations of python on your machine.
if not i'd recommend uninstalling python3.9 and installing 3.7 as it is more stable , if you dont wish to uninstall it , you are probably running a script that uses a version different of which the one you installed pandas on.

Comment: Python 3.9 final release was Oct 2020, it should be stable.

Comment: Agree, Python 3.9 Oct release is stated as a stable one. [latest release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/). OP's issue is not caused by Python version.

Comment: still the issue of  multiple python installs still could be there , he could have had installed pandas for 3.7 and is trying to run it on 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `python Excel.py` is the one you want, but you also need to do `sudo pip3 install openpyxl` and change your code to be `data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/justin/Desktop/midori.xls', engine='openpyxl')`.